# Why is creating a Float32Array with an offset that isn't a multiple of the element size not allowed?

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays

I'd like to read a binary file with a few 32 bit float values at byte offset 31.

Unfortunately, `new Float32Array(buffer, 31, 6);` does not work. An offset of 32 instead of 31 works but I need 31.

According to [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/Float32Array), offset has to be a multiple of the element size, 4 in this case.

I'm interested in the reason behind this behaviour. Why does it matter where the view starts?

The [best workaround I found thus far](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/DataView) has not made it into gecko yet so I can't use it.

Do I realy have to cut and copy the byte values into a new array to get my float values?

Comment: I suspect it's just a matter of expecting multi-byte values to be properly aligned in memory. *edit* - having the proposed ".slice()" method on ArrayBuffer would be one good workaround, because that'd let you copy odd-aligned bytes into a new well-aligned buffer.

Comment: @Pointy
I've extended ArrayBuffer with a subarray function:

ArrayBuffer.prototype.subarray = function(offset, length){
 var sub = new ArrayBuffer(length);
 var subView = new Int8Array(sub);
 var thisView = new Int8Array(this);
 
 for(var i = 0; i < length; i++ ){
  subView[i] = thisView[offset+i];
 }
 
 return sub;
}

Comment: OK yes that's probably what ".slice()" would do too :-)  It seems like an awkward set of APIs to work with; I have only recently started reading about it all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm interested in the reason behind this behaviour. Why does it matter where the view starts?

Some architectures do not allow unaligned word accesses, and there are performance penalties on architectures that do allow it such as x86 (though some instructions must be aligned).

> Do I really have to cut and copy the byte values into a new array to get my float values?

Yes, just like Markus' example you should create a new `ArrayBuffer` with a `UInt8Array` view and a `Float32Array` view for a `read_buffer` (copy with `UInt8Array` view and interpret from `Float32Array` view). Then you can read from your data with a `UInt8Array`, copy that into your `read_buffer` view and then interpret using the `Float32Array`. It's quite a seamless process.

Comment: Actually, I(Markus) am to one who asked this question, pimvdb just made some modifications.

Comment: Let's make some modifications here as well :)

Answer (score 5):

[DataView.getFloat32()](http://www.javascripture.com/DataView#getFloat32) would be the best way to do this.  DataView is designed for packed data and allows unaligned access to the data in an ArrayBuffer so you can pass in odd offsets like 31.

Comment: DataView, which I've linked to in my question, did not work back then. I have switched to it since it has been implemented.

Comment: Also, this will only get 1 number instead of getting a list of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slice` to get a new ArrayBuffer whose contents are a copy of this ArrayBuffer's bytes from begin, inclusive, up to end

```js
const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(250);
const list = buffer.slice(10); // index [11,250]
const nums = new Int32Array(list, 0, 60);
```

Comment: I'm using TypedArrays for performance. Using slice like that defeats that purpose.

Comment: for other, that doesn't care about performance this should works: let arrayData = new Uint32Array(buffer.slice(offset), 0, length);